# create *.gcda files in a desired location using GCOV_PREFIX in linux?

Tags: linux, gcov

I have a problem in using GCOV_PREFIX environment variable.

Compiler version that I am using on build machine - gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-3)

I am compiling my source files (*.c) using "fprofile-arcs –ftest-coverage" on build machine which produces an executable, object files (corresponding to each source file) and gcno file (corresponding to each source file) in the following location

/a/b/c/d

/a/b is mounted onto a test machine in the following directory "/tmp/test/a/b". On test machine, when I execute the executable, the same directory structure "a/b/c/d" is expected for creating *.gcda files. 
Since it is not available, I get an error of this kind "profiling:/a/b/c/d/xyz.gcda:Cannot open".

But I do not want to create the same directory structure in my test machine.

I want to create a directory (/tmp/gcovfiles) in my test machine and I want gcda files to be created in /tmp/gcovfiles location.

I tried using environment variables GCOV_PREFIX and GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP. But it did not have any effect. May be I am not using it properly.

Could you please help?